# Why does visual express 2008 not auto complete std::system

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does visual express 2008 not give me the option of `system` when typing `std::` though I hear it is part of the `<cstdlib>`?

Comment: @Kyle Joseph No idea why this happens, but I've noticed it too for almost all C standard headers that are wrapped by C++. It won't autocomplete the function name, but once you type it and open parenthesis, a popup appears showing the arguments and types. Seems like an Intellisense bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that system is defined in the toplevel namespace and only included into std by way of a using statement. That way it wouldn't actually be in the namespace std, but rather just be accessible through it.

There's just one toplevel or global namespace, ::. So ::global would be that function. If they'd implemented the function as

```
void system(...);
namespace std { using ::system; }
```

that would explain this behaviour. System signature may be wrong, didn't check it.

Comment: Interesting this certainly sounds logical. What counts as a top-level namespace and do you mean that `std` is a part of one of these top-level namespaces?